# JQuery: .focus() event on whole form? How to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, focus

consider the following HTML:

```
<form ....>
   <textarea>....</textarea
   <input .... />
</form>
```

Now I want to show a help section when the user is focused on ANY of the form elements. When the focus is gone the help information should too.

My idea was this:

```
$("form").focus(function(){...});
$("form").unfocus(function(){...});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks a lot for your help!

Tom

Addition: 
Thank you all a lot, it works. I used lonesomeday's solution, but there is another problem with my animations:

```
$('form').delegate(':input', 'focus', function() {

    $("#eintrag").animate({"height": "160px"}, 500)
    $("#header").animate({"height": "200px"}, 500)
    $("#container").animate({"margin-top": "240px"}, 500)
    $(".show").animate({"opacity": "0"}, 500)
    $(".hide").animate({"opacity": "1"}, 500)
    $("#header_links>p").animate({"opacity": "0"}, 500)

}).delegate(':input', 'blur', function() {

    $("#eintrag").animate({"height": "20px"}, 500)
    $(".show").animate({"opacity": "1"}, 500)
    $("#container").animate({"margin-top": "150px"}, 500)
    $(".hide").animate({"opacity": "0"}, 500)
    $("#header_links>p").animate({"opacity": "1"}, 500)
    $("#header").animate({"height": "110px"}, 500)

});
```

This means that I get the animation each time I change focus within the form. How do I change this?

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm I would just find all the input elements and bind against them e.g.

```
$(function() {
    $( '#form_id' ).find('input').focus(function() {

        //your function

    });

  $( '#form_id' ).find('input').blur(function() {

        //your function

    });

});
```

Comment: A space can be used instead of the second find and a colon should be used before `input` to include textareas: `$('#form_id :input').focus(...)` will do.

Comment: True - thanks @Tomas and @Laas, I'm fairly new to JQuery myself so looking to learn from more experienced folk!

Answer (score 2):

try using $(":input")  (mind the colon)

also the opposite event of **focus** is **blur**, not unfocus

Answer (score 2):

The problems:

1. The inverse of [`focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus) is [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/blur).  [`unfocus`](http://api.jquery.com/unfocus) unbinds a focus handler.
2. You're binding to the form element, whereas it is the elements within the form (in jQuery, these can be found with [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector)) that receive focus.

The nicest way to do this is with [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate):

```
$('form').delegate(':input', 'focus', function() {
    $('#help').show();
}).delegate(':input', 'blur', function() {
    $('#help').hide();
});
```

This is the quickest way to handle this.

[See jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bVP8x/1/).

Comment: Thank you all a lot, it works. I used your solution, but there is another problem with my animations:

Comment: I edited my original question. Any ideas how to solve the animation problem? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user731101 This can be fairly easily solved with a simple timer.  See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bVP8x/2/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

see [focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/). It is not intended to be used with 'form' elements, but with input, textarea... etc

Try

```
$("form input").focus(function(){...}).
```