# How to detect when entire form is out of focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, focus

I have a text form with an input field for name and an input field for email. On the mobile site, when the user clicks on a field, it is brought to the top of the viewport with the keypad below it. However, when either text field is de-selected, it gets stuck here and does not reset.

I have found the jquery focusOut event to reset the page zoom, but this fires whenever either field is not focused (ie. when the name fields is active and email is not). How can I detect when NEITHER input field is in focus?

Right now my form code is:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="http://" method="post" id="subForm" onsubmit="movedrop()"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fieldName" name="cm-name" placeholder="Full Name" tabindex=1 required>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="fieldEmail" name="cm-hjjhkh-hjjhkh" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" tabindex=2 required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-white btn-block subscribe" id="click-subscribe" type="submit" tabindex=3>SUBSCRIBE</button>
</form>
```

and my javascript:

```
$("form").focusout(function() {
document.body.scrollTop = 0;
console.log("focus out");
})
```

Which fires every time either field is deselected. I want it to fire when neither is selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery: .focus() event on whole form? How to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895246/jquery-focus-event-on-whole-form-how-to)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that none of the others members have become active in the meantime. Focusout just tells you when one of the input fields loses focus.

Try the following code:

```js
$("form").focusout(function() {
    var anyActive = false;
    $.each($(this).find(':input'), function(index, inputField){
        if($(inputField).is(':active')){
            anyActive = true;
        }
    });
    if(anyActive){
        $('#focusBox').html('One is active');
    } else {
        $('#focusBox').html('None is active');
    }
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-signin" action="http://" method="post" id="subForm" onsubmit="movedrop()"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fieldName" name="cm-name" placeholder="Full Name" tabindex=1 required>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" id="fieldEmail" name="cm-hjjhkh-hjjhkh" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" tabindex=2 required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-white btn-block subscribe" id="click-subscribe" type="submit" tabindex=3>SUBSCRIBE</button>
</form>

<div id="focusBox"></div>
```

Comment: I was putting my answer together and noticed yours.  +1 for detecting :active.  Seems very plausible.

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with this type of thing in the past by looking at focus events for the entire page as a whole.  Essentially, I use two flags to keep track of whether or not the form 1) has focus and 2) has ever had focus.  Then, I use a single handler for both `click` and `focusin` for the entire body the looks at the target of the event: if that target is inside the form, we know that the form hasn't lost focus.  If not and `wasFormFocused`, then we know the form has lost focus: reset the flags and do whatever else is necessary (in this case, scroll to the top).  This solution handles tabing out, clicking out, and also clicking on labels with the form.

```js
var wasFormFocused = false, isFormFocused = false;

$("#theForm").focusout(function() {
    isFormFocused = false;
});

var handleClickOrTab = function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).parents("#theForm").length) {
        wasFormFocused = true;
        return;
    }

    if (wasFormFocused && !isFormFocused) {
        wasFormFocused = false;
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        $("body").append('<br>form lost focus (scrollTop = 0)');
    }
}
$("body").click(handleClickOrTab).focusin(handleClickOrTab);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="theForm" class="form-signin" action="http://" method="post" id="subForm" onsubmit="movedrop()">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fieldName" name="cm-name" placeholder="Full Name" tabindex=1 required>
  <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
  <input type="email" id="fieldEmail" name="cm-hjjhkh-hjjhkh" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" tabindex=2 required>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-white btn-block subscribe" id="click-subscribe" type="submit" tabindex=3>SUBSCRIBE</button>
</form>

<h4>CLICK me (cause you can't tab to me)</h4>
<input type="text" placeholder="TAB to me or CLICK me">
```